# math to center an image on a screen?

Tags: image, math

Given a screen of dimensions (w,h) and a photo of dimension (ww,hh) how do I calculate the x,y point on screen to place the upper left corner of the image so the image is centered?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a homework ? It is quite simple...

Comment: @alphablender Is there a solution already? To me it seems that you didn't give all the necessary information. How is the origin of the images given?

Comment: Thanks belisarius! I didn't see the check mark. I don't (or didn't) have the right to vote anything up or down when I posted this question, maybe it will work now. Thanks for telling me. I'll be sure to help if I find something in my areas of experties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = (w/2) - (ww/2)
y = (h/2) - (hh/2)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
x = (w - ww) / 2;
y = (h - hh) / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was some simple formula like that, but I couldn't wrap my brain around it.

Comment: Hi! Can you help me with my problem with align? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545822/set-align-of-image-in-flash-and-action-script