# keep image centered when scaling and origin is upper left

Tags: math, graphics

I'm scaling and drawing an image to a smaller image. The origin of both images is the upper left corner (0,0). The larger image is 100x100px (but could be any size) and the smaller one 28x28px. That part is easy, 28/100=scaling factor

The next part is that I want to keep shrinking the image to a smaller size by reducing the scaling factor slowly, but I want the image to remain centered in the 28x28px box, and so the question is, how do I calculate the x and y offset to keep the object centered in the 28x28 box based on the scaling factor?

```
function scale(scalefactor as float,destregion as object, sourceregion as object) as object
    sourceregion.setalphaenable(true)
    destregion.setalphaenable(true)
    destregion.setscalemode(1)
    destregion.clear(&h00000000)

    xOffset= ****** getStackOverFlowHelp(???) ******
    yOffset= ****** getSTackOverflowHelp(???) ******

    destregion.drawscaledobject(xOffset,yOffset,scalefactor,scalefactor,sourceregion)
    destregion.finish()
end function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [math to center an image on a screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568582/math-to-center-an-image-on-a-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I found the answer here: 
**[Math to center an image on a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568582/math-to-center-an-image-on-a-screen)**

although the context is different...

Working function:

```
function scale(scalefactor as float,destregion as object,sourceregion as object) as object
    sourceregion.setalphaenable(true)
    destregion.setalphaenable(true)
    destregion.setscalemode(1)
    destregion.clear(&h00000000)
    ww=sourceregion.getwidth()*scalefactor
    w=destregion.getwidth()
    hh=sourceregion.getwidth()*scalefactor
    h=destregion.getwidth()
    xOffset=(w/2)-(ww/2)
    yoffset=(h/2)-(hh/2)    
    destregion.drawscaledobject(xOffset,yOffset,scalefactor,scalefactor,sourceregion)
    destregion.finish()
end function
```

Comment: embarrassing indeed, to realize you asked (~)same question couple of years before. +1 for academic honesty